# Windows　文字コードに関するエラー

Tags: python, python3, windows, 文字コード

## 現象

subprocessモジュールで、Windowsのsysteminfoを取得し、'shift-jis'デコードすると、環境によって例外が送出される。
PC1では例外発生：過去にはPC2同様問題なかった。
PC2では問題ない

ちなみにソースコード上の以下の部分を変更することで、PC1,PC2とも例外は発生しなくなります。
→**これで一旦、例外がなくなったのですが、再確認したところ、例外が発生するようになりました。**

```
textout = retout.decode('shift-jis') -> textout = retout.decode()
```

## 知りたいこと

- systeminfoの内容（環境ごとの情報の中に文字コードが異なるものがある可能性）によって発生するのか
- 環境ごとに発生するとしたら、どのように原因を調べたらよいか？（環境変数にそれらしき違いはありませんでした。）

## 環境

・Windows 10 Pro
・VScode 1.72.0
・Python 3.9.10

PC1、PC2ともに上記の環境

## 発生する例外

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'shift_jis' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 2475: illegal multibyte sequence
```

## ソースコード

```
import json
import subprocess

cmd_list = ['systeminfo', '/fo', 'LIST']

cmdreturn = subprocess.run(
    cmd_list, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

retcode = cmdreturn.returncode
retout = cmdreturn.stdout
#textout = retout.decode()
try:
    textout = retout.decode('shift-jis')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    raise e

text_list = textout.splitlines()


param_dict = dict()
c_key = None

for text_line in text_list:
    if not text_line.startswith(' '):
        if ':' in text_line:
            key_word = text_line.split(':', maxsplit=1)
            if key_word[1].startswith(' '):
                key_word[1] = key_word[1].lstrip()
            param_dict.setdefault(key_word[0], key_word[1])
            c_key = key_word[0]
    else:
        temp = text_line.lstrip()
        if '\t' in temp:
            temp = temp.split('\t')
            temp = ''.join(temp)
        if c_key in param_dict:
            c_data = param_dict[c_key]
            if isinstance(c_data, list):
                set_list = c_data
                set_list.append(temp)
                pass
            else:
                set_list = [c_data, temp]
                param_dict[c_key] = set_list
else:
    ret_dump = json.dumps(param_dict, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

print(ret_dump)
```

## 追加試験

### 文字コード指定

localeモジュールにより、システムのエンコードを取得し、これをdecode時に指定しました。結果は同じで､0x97がErrorとなります。

バイナリエディタの該当部分をコピペして、サクラエディタに貼り付けると、「・」という表示になりました。
コマンドプロンプトで、systeminfo /fo LISTを実行した結果の該当行は、以下の表示になります。

```
接続名:           イーサネット 5
```

### ソースコード改訂

```
import json
import locale
import subprocess

cmd_list = ['systeminfo', '/fo', 'LIST']

cmdreturn = subprocess.run(
    cmd_list, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

local_encode = locale.getdefaultlocale()
if local_encode:
    language_code, encoding = local_encode

    retcode = cmdreturn.returncode
    retout = cmdreturn.stdout

    with open('systeminfo.bin','bw') as f:
        f.write(retout)
    #textout = retout.decode()
    try:
        textout = retout.decode(encoding)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e

    text_list = textout.splitlines()


    param_dict = dict()
    c_key = None

    for text_line in text_list:
        if not text_line.startswith(' '):
            if ':' in text_line:
                key_word = text_line.split(':', maxsplit=1)
                if key_word[1].startswith(' '):
                    key_word[1] = key_word[1].lstrip()
                param_dict.setdefault(key_word[0], key_word[1])
                c_key = key_word[0]
        else:
            temp = text_line.lstrip()
            if '\t' in temp:
                temp = temp.split('\t')
                temp = ''.join(temp)
            if c_key in param_dict:
                c_data = param_dict[c_key]
                if isinstance(c_data, list):
                    set_list = c_data
                    set_list.append(temp)
                    pass
                else:
                    set_list = [c_data, temp]
                    param_dict[c_key] = set_list
    else:
        ret_dump = json.dumps(param_dict, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

        print(ret_dump)
```

### 発生する例外

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp932' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 2475: illegal multibyte sequence
```

### バイナリエディタ

バイナリを出力してエディタで表示した結果画像を貼り付けます。
ちなみに、PC2では該当部分に0x97というバイトは存在しません。

[image: バイナリエディタ表示]

## 再追加試験

コマンドプロンプトで、以下のコマンドを実行

```
systeminfo /fo LIST > output.txt
```

この結果を以下のPythonスクリプトでバイナリ化

```
with open('output.txt','br') as f:
    txt = f.read()

with open('output.bin','bw') as f:
    f.write(txt)
```

追加試験時とのバイナリ比較をVScode上で表示
[image: バイナリ比較]

subprocessモジュールによるstdoutでは日本語出力がうまく実行できないと考えてよいのでしょうか？

さらにsubprocessモジュールのencoding引数に、localeモジュールで取得したencodingを指定すると、0x97で引っかかって例外出力されます。cp932,utf-8,shift-jisを試しましたが結果が同じでした。

Comment: VSCode はあくまでエディタなので、より具体的には Python をどのように実行しているか (コマンドプロンプト or PowerShell) 辺りの情報を書いた方が回答の参考になりそうです。

Comment: 関係するかどうか不明ですが、`shift_jis`類似の指定だと微妙に違いがあるようです。[Python♪Windowsの「Shift JIS」の落とし穴](https://snowtree-injune.com/2020/05/15/codec-py003/), [Windows の文字コードは Python では cp932](https://criticabug.hatenablog.com/entry/python-cp932), [Pythonで学ぶ文字コード](https://qiita.com/ny7760/items/d9c247781a790210936d) デフォルトのままか`cp932`でしょうかね。

Comment: 問題が再現出来るなら、発生する装置で`retout = cmdreturn.stdout`の結果を`retout.decode()`せずにそのままバイナリデータとしてファイルに書き出して、そのファイルの`position 2475`あるいは付近にある`0x97`がどのような文字の一部(上位バイトor下位バイト)かを調べてみてはどうでしょう？ 実際のデータが何であるかを特定することが調査の近道になるのでは？

Comment: 追加試験をしてみました。

Comment: 英語の(あるいは日本語では無い)モード時に通知されるシステムのデータそのものがおかしな値になっているのでは？ その`Connection Name:`で通知されるデータを変更することは出来ないのでしょうか？

Comment: systeminfo で表示される内容はユーザ依存となるため、アプリケーション都合での変更は難しいと考えております。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

日本語環境以外では当然ShiftJIS/CP932以外もあり得ますし、日本語環境でもWindows 10以降ではUTF-8/CP65001になっている場合もあります。
Pythonのバージョン、Windowsのコードページ設定、環境変数のPYTHONIOENCODINGやPYTHONUTF8などを調べるのはどうでしょうか？

追加分についてSJISやCP932の第2バイトとして3Fは未使用領域のはずなのに3F 97 3Fという出力になってるので、何かsysteminfoが不適切な出力をする条件があるんだと思います。

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8932

エラーになりさえしなければ良いという用途であれば `textout = retout.decode('shift-jis', errors='replace')` のような対応はできますが当然情報は失われます。

Comment: コマンドプロンプトでは、現在のコードページ　932(ANSI/OEM  - 日本語 Shift-JIS)となっており、環境変数は特に設定されていませんでした。

Comment: となると、kunifさんのコメントにあるデータをダンプしての解析でしょうか

Comment: ありがとうございます。今回の取得情報でエラーが発生する箇所は単なる名前の部分なので、errors='replace'引数による変更の対処で大丈夫でした。最終目的は、ファイルへの出力なので、'systeminfo.bin'→'systeminfo.txt'とするだけでも目的には合致しました。不思議なことに、バイナリモードでtxtファイルに書き込むと、正しく日本語になる場合がある（ならないこともある。上記のソースコードでは日本語化しない。）のです。

Comment: ちなみに、PC1において、コントロールパネル：地域：管理タブ：システムロケールの変更ダイアログで、□ベータ：ワールドワイド言語サポートでUnicode UTF-8を使用にチェックを入れると、CP65001となり、チェックを入れないとCP932となります。